# HTML Tables using JPG images as borders

Tags: html, html-table, border

I'm trying to create a "certificate" for use in an email capmaign. We are trying to maintain compatability with Outlook 2007 and that limits us from using the background property to just load a single picture to display behind the text.

I've chopped my borders up in 4 pieces (left, top, right, bottom) and placed them in spanned columns and rows but cannot get them to line up properly. Any suggestions based on this code?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Special Offer from Toyota/Scion of Clifton Park</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
.style1 {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif}
.style2 {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: small;
    font-style: italic;
}
.style4 {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
}
.style8 {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-style: italic;
    color: #666666;
}
.style9 {color: #666666}
.style10 {color: #000000}

}
-->
</style>
</head>

<body>
<table width="610" height="984" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr></tr>


  <tr>
  <td width="74" rowspan="11"><img src="http://pbrgraphics.com/Constant_Contact/TCP/cert_borders/left_image2.jpg" alt="Left Image" width="70" height="984" align="top" /></td>
  <td colspan="5"><img src="http://pbrgraphics.com/Constant_Contact/TCP/cert_borders/top_image3.jpg" alt="Top Image" width="461" height="171" align="left" /></td>
  <td width="87" rowspan="11"><img src="http://pbrgraphics.com/Constant_Contact/TCP/cert_borders/right_image2.jpg" border=0 alt="Right Image" width="71" height="984" align="bottom" /></td>
</tr>
  <tr>
  <td colspan="5">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
  <td colspan="5">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
  <tr>
  <td colspan="5">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
  <tr>
  <td colspan="5">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
  <tr>
  <td colspan="5">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
  <tr>
  <td colspan="5">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>

  <tr>
  <td colspan="5">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>

  <tr>
  <td colspan="5">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>

  <tr>
  <td width="90">&nbsp;</td>
  <td width="90">&nbsp;</td>
  <td width="90">&nbsp;</td>
  <td width="90">&nbsp;</td>
  <td width="91">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
  <tr>
  <td colspan="5"><div align="center">
    <p class="style4">&nbsp;</p>
    <p class="style4">&nbsp;</p>
    <p class="style4">&nbsp;</p>
    <p class="style4">&nbsp;</p>
    <p class="style4">&nbsp;</p>
    <p class="style4">&nbsp;</p>
    <p class="style4">&nbsp;</p>
    <p class="style4">&nbsp;</p>
    <p class="style4">&nbsp;</p>
    <p class="style4">&nbsp;</p>
    <p class="style4">&nbsp;</p>
    <p class="style4">&nbsp;</p>
    <p class="style4">&nbsp;</p>
    <p class="style4">&nbsp;</p>
    <p class="style4">&nbsp;</p>
    <p class="style4">&nbsp;</p>
    <p class="style4"><span class="style8"><br/> 
      </span><img src="http://pbrgraphics.com/Constant_Contact/TCP/cert_borders/bottom_image2.jpg" alt="Bottom Image" width="466" height="63" align="top" /><br />
    </p>
    </div></td>
</tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all your suggestions - GREAT HELP! Here's what I ended up with if you are curious. Previews wrong in browsers, but displays correctly in email clients on the receiving end. I tested Gmail, Outlook 2000/2007, Yahoo (old/new), Hotmail, Thunderbird successfully.

Also found this guide to CSS in emails http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/
(basically avoid it if sending to Outlook 2007/2010 and Gmail clients)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<style type="text/css">
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ */
/* v1.0 | 20080212 */

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    background: #FFF;
    text-align: left;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}

/* remember to define focus styles! */
:focus {
    outline: 0;
}

/* remember to highlight inserts somehow! */
ins {
    text-decoration: none;
}
del {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}

/* tables still need 'cellspacing="0"' in the markup */
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
body table tr td {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
</style>
<body>
<table width="600" height="984" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;>    
<tr>
<td valign="top" width="74" rowspan="3"><img src="http://pbrgraphics.com/Constant_Contact/TCP/cert_borders/left_image2.jpg" alt="Left Image" width="70" height="984" /></td>

<td valign="top"><img src="http://pbrgraphics.com/Constant_Contact/TCP/cert_borders/top_image3.jpg" alt="Top Image" width="459" height="171" /></td>

<td valign="top" width="71" rowspan="3"><img src="http://pbrgraphics.com/Constant_Contact/TCP/cert_borders/right_image2.jpg" border=0 alt="Right Image" width="71" height="984" /></td>
</tr> 
<tr>
<td>
  <p align="center"><font size="+1"> <strong>Special Introductory Maintenance Offer for:</strong></font></p>
  <p align="center"><em>Insert Name<br />Insert Vehicle<br />Insert Vin#<br />Insert Delivery Date</em></p>
  <p align="center"><strong>First 5,000 Miles / 6 Months <br /> Maintenance Service<br />$29.95<br /><font size="-4">(a $79.95 value)<br/><br/><font size="-1">to include:<br /></strong></p>
    <ul>
    <li><div align="left">Inspect and top off washer fluid, brake fluid, <br />
        power steering fluid, and coolant level</div></li>
    <li><div align="left"><font size="-1">Set tire pressures and rotate tires</div></li>
    <li><div align="left">Thorough tire inspection for abnormal wear or damage</div></li>
    <li><div align="left">Inspect wiper blades</div></li>
    <li><div align="left">Replace engine oil and filter</div></li>
    <li><div align="left">Reset maintenance indicator </div></li>
    </font>
    </ul>

  <p align="left"><font size="-1"><span>Toyota of Clifton Park would like to <strong>Thank You</strong> for  your vehicle purchase. We have taken time in caring for and preparing  your vehicle before your purchase and would like to continue that same  care throughout your ownership. I personally invite you to take  advantage of the above offer for your first full Toyota scheduled  maintenance in our Award winning service department. The initial &quot;break  in&quot; inspection is crucial to the safety and longevity of your new  investment.<br /><br />
    Our call center will be following up with you as a reminder when the time gets close. If you have any questions or concerns please don't  hesitate to call the service department at 518-664-4444. Any one of our associates can answer your questions. We truly appreciate your business and look forward to seeing you soon.</span></font></p>

<p align="center"><span>Thank You, <br />Jason Halliday, Service Manager<br />Toyota / Scion of Clifton Park<br /><font size="-3"><em><br /><br />Certificate expires 6 months from delivery date or <br />5,000 miles, whichever comes first.<br />Applicable sales tax not included.<br />Certificate not transferable, valid only for the above customer and vehicle.<br /> NC OPCODE FSCERT<br /></em></font></span></p>
</td>     
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="bottom"><img src="http://pbrgraphics.com/Constant_Contact/TCP/cert_borders/bottom_image2.jpg" alt="Bottom Image" width="459" height="63"/></td>     
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

All of your middle column cells have variable heights (not fixed) and so the browser will just try to adjust them to what it thinks is best.

You need to fix their heights by using the style attribute like so:

```
<td style="height: 171px;">
```

That would be for the cell containing the top image as the image has a height of 171px.

Also: Do you need 9 rows in the center? Or did you try that to position the borders?

**Edit:** Or what Re0sless said. ;D

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by adding  *valign="top"* and  *valign="bottom"* to the center cells in the top and bottom for the  table.

like so:

```
<tr>
  <td width="74" rowspan="11"><img src="left_image2.jpg"  width="70" height="984" align="top" /></td>
  <td colspan="5" valign="top"><img src="top_image3.jpg" width="461" height="171" align="left" /></td>
  <td width="87" rowspan="11" ><img src="http:right_image2.jpg" border=0  width="71" height="984" align="bottom" /></td>
</tr>
......
<tr  valign="bottom">
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestions:

1. Set the image widths to the proper values (top and bottom are 459px wide).
2. Set the table width to the total value (459 + 71 + 71 = 600).
3. Create a separate row for the bottom image, and put all of your content in one table cell. You can nest more tables inside if you need to.

```
<table width="600" height="984" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
       <td width="74" rowspan="3"><img src="http://pbrgraphics.com/Constant_Contact/TCP/cert_borders/left_image2.jpg" alt="Left Image" width="70" height="984" align="top" /></td>
       <td><img src="http://pbrgraphics.com/Constant_Contact/TCP/cert_borders/top_image3.jpg" alt="Top Image" width="459" height="171" align="left" /></td>
       <td width="71" rowspan="3"><img src="http://pbrgraphics.com/Constant_Contact/TCP/cert_borders/right_image2.jpg" border=0 alt="Right Image" width="71" height="984" align="bottom" /></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>Put all your content in here.</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td valign="bottom"><img src="http://pbrgraphics.com/Constant_Contact/TCP/cert_borders/bottom_image2.jpg" alt="Bottom Image" width="459" height="63" align="top" /></td>
     </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

... there are couple of ways to fix it, one (if it will work in outlook and display in all other mail agents) would be to position the top and bottom border images absolutely in the cells.

Second, I'd restructure the table maybe. Make the top and bottom borders span all the columns, as if they were capping the table from top and bottom and take it from there.

Answer (score 0):

1. Set the top middle cell to vertical align top:
   .... top_image3.jpg ....

2.
Cut a new image to use for the bottom which includes the left, middle, and right columns of the entire table and throw it in a cell with a colspan="7"

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you [reset all your CSS](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) so that margin and padding is at 0 before you apply any styles.

Answer (score 0):

After hunting around on this question for my own requirements of "HTML Tables using images as borders" I came to a solution that I did not see elsewhere.  It uses a separate background on the tbody, tr and td to achieve the desired effect.  Here is the IE8 (CSS2) compatible solution:

```
table.table tbody {
      background-color: #dddddd;
}

table.table tbody tr td, table.table thead tr th {
    background-image: url('some-image.png');
    background-position: right;
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
}

table.table tbody tr {
    background-image: url('some-image.png');
    background-position: top;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

The solution in CSS3 is to use multiple backgrounds:

```
table.table tbody tr td, table.table thead tr th {
      background-image: url('some-image.png'), url('some-image.png');
      background-position: top, right;
      background-repeat: repeat-x, repeat-y;
}
```

Hope this helps someone in the future.