# display a border image on a table row with flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

Hi I have found posts regarding putting a image border around a table row... none too successful... however  these pre date the implementation of flexbox...

e.g: [HTML Tables using JPG images as borders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249218/html-tables-using-jpg-images-as-borders)

surely it is possible now to put an image around a table row and align the table cells as per a standard html table (or close enough)

http://jsfiddle.net/6yu8jh7p/5/

I tried using flexbox but i found that it affected the flow of its child elements and I want those elements to remain in the normal HTML flow of the page.

see below:

```
tr[draggable] {
                    display: flex;
                flex-flow: row;
                justify-content: space-between;
                border-style: solid;
                border-width: 5px;
                border-color: transparent;
                -moz-border-image: url(url) 5 repeat;
                -webkit-border-image: url(url) 5 repeat;
                -o-border-image: url(url) 5 repeat;
                border-image: url(url) 5 repeat;
                padding: 5px;
                margin: 10px 0;

            }
                    tr[draggable]  td{
                         display: flex;
                        flex-basis: 0;
                        display: flex;
                    }
                         tr[draggable]  td:first-child{
                          flex-grow: 6;
                          flex-flow: column;

                        }
                        tr[draggable]  td:last-child{
                            flex-grow: 1;
                        }
```

Comment: flexbox isn't a cure-all for stuff you couldn't do before and is unlikely to be a solution here without dispensing with a table and using a more standard div based structure.

Comment: Keep in mind that `table` and its child elements are defined solely by their CSS `display` properties. Once you alter the `display` properties, like you have done with `tr`, they are no longer table rows (or tables or table cells). Aside from that, @Paulie_D is correct, flexbox is not designed for all CSS challenges.